# Error with deserialization - Lists and objects

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a issue with deserialization. Here is the error returned:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SmartTransportNatif.Stations' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

I have this part of a json returned from a server:

```
"stations": {
        "from": [
            {
                "id": "008501120",
                "name": "Lausanne",
                "score": 101,
                "coordinate": {
                    "type": "WGS84",
                    "x": 46.516777,
                    "y": 6.629095
                },
                "distance": null
            }
        ],
        "to": [
            {
                "id": "000000178",
                "name": "Fribourg",
                "score": null,
                "coordinate": {
                    "type": "WGS84",
                    "x": 46.803272,
                    "y": 7.151027
                },
                "distance": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here are my objects for deserialization:

```
 public class RootObject2
    {
        public List<Connection> connections { get; set; }
        public Station from { get; set; }
        public Station to { get; set; }
        public Stations stations { get; set; }
    }

 public class Stations
    {
        [JsonProperty("from")]
        public List<Station> from { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public List<Station> to { get; set; }
    }


  public class Station
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object score { get; set; }
        public Coordinate coordinate { get; set; }
        public double distance { get; set; }
    }
```

As the error mentions, it is the type "Stations" that cause the error, but I don't see what is wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is simple: this JSON is **invalid**. JSON should either represent an object or an array.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev This is the final property of a long JSON

Comment: Ok, I see. You need to post the minimal valid JSON so that everybody can reproduce this problem. You can just take the whole JSON and remove all unnecessary items, but it should be valid.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev here is the url where I get the JSON : 
http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=lausanne&to=fribourg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work from it backwards first, here are your classes:

> Look at these carefully, as I have **correctly mapped the types** for each property, based on your json object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Stations Stations { get; set; }
}

public class Stations
{
    public List<Station> From { get; set; }
    public List<Station> To { get; set; }
}


public class Station
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Score { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
    public double? Distance { get; set; }
}

public struct Coordinate
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a sample of your classes, constructed to make your desired `RootObject`.

```
var data = new RootObject()
{
    Stations = new Stations()
    {
        From = new List<Station>()
        {
            new Station()
            {
                Id = "008501120",
                Name = "Lausanne",
                Score = 101,
                Coordinate = new Coordinate {Type = "WGS84", X = 46.516777, Y = 6.629095},
                Distance = null
            }
        },
        To = new List<Station>()
        {
            new Station()
            {
                Id = "000000178",
                Name = "Fribourg",
                Score = null,
                Coordinate = new Coordinate {Type = "WGS84", X = 46.803272, Y = 7.151027},
                Distance = null
            }
        }
    }
};

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

The value you get back looks like this:

```
{
  "Stations": {
    "From": [
      {
        "Id": "008501120",
        "Name": "Lausanne",
        "Score": 101,
        "Coordinate": {
          "Type": "WGS84",
          "X": 46.516777,
          "Y": 6.629095
        },
        "Distance": null
      }
    ],
    "To": [
      {
        "Id": "000000178",
        "Name": "Fribourg",
        "Score": null,
        "Coordinate": {
          "Type": "WGS84",
          "X": 46.803272,
          "Y": 7.151027
        },
        "Distance": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This works fine in reverse.

```
var foo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

---

## Proof that it works

http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=lausanne&to=fribourg
Based on your link above, here are the classes in action

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
    .Create("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=lausanne&to=fribourg");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadLine();
    var foo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
}
```

Works fine.

---

## Your Error Message

The error that you are getting:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type **'SmartTransportNatif.Stations'** because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

This points to a class that you're not even showing in your question, which is just modeled incorrectly to the json. But since it wasn't provided along with your question, the answer above show be adequate to show where you're going wrong.

Comment: Well the value you get back it exactly the same as I receive. I deduct that the classes are correct. I changed the types to correspond to your solution, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: @A.Silva - I've added the example code to prove it to you in my recent edit.

Comment: your answer is totally correct, I found that my problem was another one, my JSON variable that I use to deserialise has the same value of an other previous request I do before that one. So the JSON is not the one I was expecting.


Thank you

Comment: @A.Silva - no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are missing `{}` in the front and at the end. If so, check below:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public Coordinate coordinate { get; set; }
    public object distance { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinate2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

public class To
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object score { get; set; }
    public Coordinate2 coordinate { get; set; }
    public object distance { get; set; }
}

public class Stations
{
    public List<From> from { get; set; }
    public List<To> to { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Stations stations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: From bottom to top

Comment: Why is there a "From" and "To" distinct objects if they have the same attributes?